# Integrating TensorFlow with OpenCL using bazel

Tags: tensorflow, opencl, bazel

**Description of the problem / feature request / question:**

I am trying to use bazel to build TensorFlow Library. It builds fine.

**Additional Feature :**
I would like to add OpenCL code in one of the files of TensorFlow. Added all the required code
AND added the following in one of the build files (`tensorflow/core/BUILD`), considering 'opencl' as the root directory of opencl.

```
cc_library( name = "opencl", hdrs=glob(["opencl/include/CL/*h"]),
visibility =["//visibility:public"], )

cc_library( name="all_kernels" , visibility= ["//visibility:public"],
copts=tf_copts() + ["-Ithird_party/opencl/include"], deps= [
"//third_party/opencl", ],
```

**example to reproduce the problem:**

By running
bazel build `//tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo --fat_apk_cpu=armeabi-v7a --copt="-Ithird_party/opencl/include"`

**Issues Faced while building :**

```
error: undefined reference to 'clEnqueueReadBuffer'
error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseMemObject'
error: undefined reference to 'clReleaseMemObject'
```

etc

Environment info

Operating System: Ubuntu 17.04

Bazel version (output of bazel info release): release 0.5.1

**relevant searching on web?**

[How to add external header files during bazel/tensorflow build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761469/how-to-add-external-header-files-during-bazel-tensorflow-build/37844376)

**information or logs or outputs that would be helpful?**

```
bazel-out/android-arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/libandroid_tensorflow_kernels.lo(conv_ops.o):conv_ops.cc:function
matrixMul(float*, float*, int, int, int, int, int, int): error:
undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs'
```

I tried linking directly to libOpenCL.so as shown below by referring https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/tutorial/cpp.html#adding-dependencies-on-precompiled-libraries
, but still same issue

```
cc_library( name = "opencl", srcs = glob(["lib/x86_64/.so"]), hdrs =
glob(["include/CL/.h"]), visibility = ["//visibility:public"], )
```

Please help me in resolving the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libOpenCL.so was red in color in terminal, which meant it was archived, replaced the file and issue is resolved